# Java Number Format Exception using

Tags: java, swing, exception, parseint, actionevent

I want to use `NumberFormatException` but my code have error, because I have `TextField` and a button in my program. If you enter the number in textfield, there is not any problem.
If you enter a letter, I want to get error message but I don't use. please help me?
        my code

```
private  JTextField t1=new JTextField(10);
private  JButton o88 = new JButton("send");

try{
   o88.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           int a = 0;
           a = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText()); 
       }
   });
}
catch (NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println( e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It looks like your executable code is placed outside a method, a constructor, or an initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the try/catch in the wrong place. You need to put it inside the actionPerformed method.

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e ) {
   try {
    int a = Integer.parseInt( t1.getText() );
   }
   catch(NumberFormatException e ) {
     System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
   }
 }
```